# find : $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x{(1 + \sin2t)^{1/t}dt}$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I have been working on challenging questions recently, and I found the following question I would be so grateful if anyone could help me solve this question.

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x{(1 + \sin2t)^{1/t}dt}$

Thank you everyone

Comment: Hint: LHopital's Rule and Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x{(1 + \sin2t)^{1/t}dt}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\int_0^x{(1 + \sin2t)^{1/t}dt}}{x}$ then use LHopital's Rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using lhopitals and FTC we have

$$ \lim_{x \to 0 } (1 + \sin 2x )^{1/x} = \lim_{x \to 0} e^{ \frac{1}{x}  \ln (1 + \sin 2x )} = e^A$$

where

$$ A = \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{ \ln(1 + \sin 2x) }{x} $$

by continuity of $x \to e^x$ and to evaluate $A$ we again use lhopitals

$$ A = \lim_{x \to 0  } \frac{ 2 \cos 2x }{1 + \sin 2x } =2 $$

Thus, the answer is $\boxed{ e^2} $